# does this variable get hoisted no matter what?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Does `var foo` get hoisted to the top of the stack even when the code inside the false block isn't ever going to be executed?

```
function foo(){
    if ( false ) {
       var foo = 'bar'; //will this be hoisted even if its never executed?
    }
}
```

I'm seeing that it is and was just confused...I didn't expect it to get hoisted in its wrapped in a false condition.

Comment: Yes, in addition, foo is undefined before and after the if condition inside foo().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; the hoisting happens before the code is run, so whether or not the `if` statement comes out `true` or `false` isn't yet known.